# Check engine light is on, and my car shakes slightly and just slowly stops moving/stops altogether when I slow down or stop

Tags: chevrolet, equinox

There's no weird noises or anything... Just the car shaking a little with the check engine light on. When I break or slow down, it starts shaking a bit and slowly stops moving. The gas pedal doesn't do anything either. The electronics are all working as far as I can tell, and we just replaced the battery a couple months ago... I have a 2013 Chevy Equinox.

Comment: There's no question in your question, so if it's "What should I do?", your first step is to find out why the check engine light is on by reading codes. If you can drive the car safely, drive it to an auto parts store and ask them to read the codes for you. Most will do it for free, hoping to sell you parts. Be prepared to write down all the codes -- the numbers, not the descriptions. Accuracy is important. Come back when you have codes so we can help you decide on the next steps after that. Use the EDIT link on your question to add codes and try to ask a specific question.